# How to transfer checked value of a radio button to a text view in another activity?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have 2 activities.
In activity An I have a radio group consist of 4 radio buttons.

In activity B, I have an empty text view.
the user can only choose one radio button.

I want to transfer the checked value of a radio button to the text view ,which is in the second activity.

Update:I've found the solution here.
https://www.mycodingcorner.com/2015/01/android-passing-data-from-one-activity.html
If you are struggling with passing data,this is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object `implements Serializable` that holds the values of the `RadioButton` and the `Spinner`, and pass this object to the activity as an extra to the `Intent` that starts the activity using it.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, TargetActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("myObject", myObject);
startActivity(intent);
```

`myObject` is the model that holds the values

Another way is to pass this object within `EventBus` or `Observable`.

Comment: Thank you, i figured out the spinner ,but i'm having problem with passing the value of radio button selected.

Comment: if this was helpful answer, please mark it as the correct answer

Comment: Actually i didn't use your answer. i tried another way.
https://www.mycodingcorner.com/2015/01/android-passing-data-from-one-activity.html